# CUPS and Gutenprint

Tags: printing, cups

Can anyone help shed light on the main differences between CUPS and Gutenprint? My initial investigation has left me confused almost as if they both depend on each other. They both call themselves drivers, but can also operate in their own capacity?

Does installing CUPS also install Gutenprint? What about visa-versa? I havent explicitly installed Gutenprint but I see references to Gutenprint drivers on the system.

Why does [lpinfo -v](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpinfo.html) list some printers prefixed with `gutenPrint53+usb://` whereas some are simply prefixed with `usb://`? Is this because Gutenprint recognizes the printer and knows which drivers it requires?

To add some context, I'm familiar with the CUPS interface but am more concerned with configuration via `lpadmin`.

Comment: See ´Description´, and file list in the links. cups-2.2.8 http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/50553829/dir/fedora_29/com/cups-2.2.8-5.fc29.x86_64.rpm.html .... gutenprint-5.2.14 http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/56289670/dir/fedora_29/com/gutenprint-5.2.14-4.fc29.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 0):

As for:

> Why does lpinfo -v list some printers prefixed with gutenPrint53+usb:// whereas some are simply prefixed with usb://?

It says in https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.3/5.3.4/ under `D) CUPS dye-sublimation backend" explains about it.` following:

```
A new CUPS backend was added to support specific dye-sublimation USB
printers that require a special communications protocol. This backend is
called 'gutenprint53+usb' and currently supports the models listed below...
```